# How to pass msg.sender and constructor params in truffle tests?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-test

I have the following constructor:

```
constructor(address _payee) public {
    payer = msg.sender;
    payee = _payee;
}
```

And this function in my JavaScript tests:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    contract = await Contract.new(payee);
});
```

However, I get an error:

> Error: Contract contract constructor expected 1 arguments, received 2

I made sure I cleared the `build` folder and I had recompiled the contracts with `truffle compile --all` before.

How can I pass `msg.sender` and `payee`? There are no problems with these constructor params when deploying the contract using the migrations deployer.

Using ganache `1.2.1` and truffle `4.1.13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I simply had to **restart** ganache. There was an old version of the contract deployed, and most likely that caused incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

It might depend on your versions, but my test files use `beforeEach(async function () {` - a bit different syntax. Make sure that's not an issue for you.

Are you importing the `Contract` correctly with something like `const Contract = artifacts.require('MyContract');`? (by the way I'm not sure if you get problems with using exactly the name `Contract` for the variable name - use another name to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the code should work! Apparently it was about ganache.

The syntax is different as I'm using es8 and haha yeah I'm not actually using `Contract` as the contract name. I simplified the nomenclature for the SO question.